# The sequence of range-exponentiated integers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

Consider a triangle where the **N**th row (1-indexed) is the array of the first **N** positive integer powers of **N**. Here are the first few rows:

```
N | Triangle

1 | 1
2 | 2 4
3 | 3 9 27
4 | 4 16 64 256
5 | 5 25 125 625 3125
...
```

Now if we concatenate those powers into a single sequence, we get OEIS [A075363](https://oeis.org/A075363):

```
1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 256, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, 6, 36, 216, 1296, 7776, 46656 ...
```

---

Given an integer **N**, your task is to return the **N**th term of this sequence. You can choose either 0 or 1-indexing.

### Test cases

**1-indexed:**

```
N  -> Output

1  -> 1
2  -> 2
3  -> 4
5  -> 9
10 -> 256
12 -> 25
15 -> 3125
```

**0-indexed:**

```
N  -> Output

0  -> 1
1  -> 2
2  -> 4
4  -> 9
9  -> 256
11 -> 25
14 -> 3125
```

Note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), thus the  shortest valid submission in each language wins!

Comment: I think there is some error in test cases: in 1-indexed 10 should be  256; in 0-indexed 9 should be 256.

Comment: Can we have trailing spaces?

Comment: @StanStrum Yes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

**1-indexed**

```python
f=lambda x,n=1:n**x*(x<=n)or f(x-n,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADArzgmsQ7BQRD7mIhWBZuW0iG@Pt7Vr99FZ/cUX8n7IYMFjbwqkRHYFhVLGxLYpEFHRq/t0Q6UpUIKTfQ6gQMviOg/)

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
!ṁṠM^ḣN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HhzsaHOxf4xj3csdjv////hqYA)

1-indexed

#### Explanation:

```
      N   Get the list of all natural numbers
 ṁ        Map over each n in that list and then concatenate
  Ṡ  ḣ      Create the range [1,n] then ...
   M^       raise n to the power of each
!         Index into that sequence
```

Answer (score 5):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

```
r=Range;Flatten[r@#^r@r@#][[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVei4KCloPG/yDYoMS891dotJ7GkJDUvushBOa7IAUjGRkcrx8aq/ddUqFNwLCpKrATShgYG/wE)

Ranges to the power of ranges of ranges...

Comment: `Range@Range@3` returns `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}`?! Damn, Mathematica's list-threading is insane.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

*-2 bytes porting [Halvard Hummel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148574/67312)*

```r
function(N){while(N>T){N=N-T;T=T+1};T^N}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Pw0@zujwjMydVw88uRLPaz9ZPN8Q6xDZE27DWOiTOr/Z/cWJBQU6lhqGVoYFOmuZ/AA)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), (original answer) 42 bytes

```r
function(N)(rep(1:N,1:N)^sequence(1:N))[N]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Pw09Toyi1QMPQyk8HiDXjilMLS1PzklNBIpqa0X6x/4sTCwpyKoF8QwOdNM3/AA)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*

```apl
⊢⊃∘∊⍳*⍳¨∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYsedTU/6pjxqKPrUe9mLSA@tALE7d0MVABk9m42NAAA)

**How?**

`⍳¨∘⍳` - create a range for each number in the range of input

`⍳*` - raise each number in the range of input to the corresponding powers

`∊` - flatten

`⊢⊃` - pick the nth element

Comment: Trying it online the code appears to be 17 bytes and it does not appear to accept a scalar integer argument or produce a single integer output

Comment: @Graham Online, the code is assigned to a variable `f` (thus `f←` is 2 more bytes, which is not counted here), and there is a test harness that returns the results from `1` to `10`.

Comment: Surely you must count all bytes including any such assignments and those required to take in the input according to the question spec and to output according to the spec. My APL answer prompts for screen input.

Comment: @Graham this is a dyalog APL dfns. It does not require assignment to be applied on any input, the TIO outlet is just for comfortable view

Comment: On that basis can I assume I can assign n within my workspace prior to running the APL one liner and thereby save 7 bytes, I am not sure our fellow competitors will accept that.

Comment: @Graham no, you can't. Where do you see any variable assigned? I only assign f to show the almost-exact byte count in the link, but it can be run as well without it. One of the highest upvoted IOs in meta is **input through function arguments**, and that's what this solution uses. And since you got a response, please remove the falsy comments. They distract other people.

Comment: @Graham your solution uses direct input rather than a tradfn or dfns - therefore you assign n. This one doesn't need to, as well as the third APL solution here.

Comment: OK I am not familiar with dfns or "input through function arguments" so if others here are content with your approach I withdraw my falsy comments. I would still like to see how your line of code would produce an answer with no other input

Comment: @Graham [like that](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u22A2%u2283%u2218%u220A%u2373*%u2373%A8%u2218%u2373%29%205&run)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68984/discussion-between-graham-and-uriel).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
*R$€Ẏ⁸ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18rSOVR05qHu/oeNe54uLv7////hqYA)

-1 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).

1-indexed.

Comment: Awesome code right here.

Comment: Getting rid of fancy syntax with `"`, my own solution is 7 bytes: `*R$€F⁸ị`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, although I had already removed the `"`, but still. That's what you get for having to study history :/

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to xnor.

```hs
([n^m|n<-[1..],m<-[1..n]]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyM6Ly63Js9GN9pQTy9WJxfCyIuNVVTU/J@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCbWKCQphBtoKdnZBD7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

0-indexed

Comment: It's actually shorter to use the list comp `[n^i|n<-[1..],i<-[1..n]]`.

Comment: Oh, I was comparing it to the `>>=` form ...

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
{⍵⌷∊*∘⍳⍨¨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bH/Vsf9TRpfWoY8aj3s2PelccWgGmt9YClSgYmgIA)

Uses 1-indexing

Saved 2 bytes with `↑,/ → ∊`, taken from [Graham's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148589/71256)

Note that in the test link, the code requires an extra `f←`, but this is not counted as per our rules.

Comment: Very clever use of `∘` with `⍨`.

Comment: `{⍵⌷∊*∘⍳⍨¨⍳⍵}` → `⊢⌷∘∊((*∘⍳)⍨¨⍳)` → `⊢⌷∘∊(⍳(*∘⍳)¨⍳)` → `⊢⌷∘∊⍳*∘⍳¨⍳`

Comment: I would post that... if I had any idea how that worked

Comment: `⊢` is to a tacit function what `⍵` is to a dfn. The `∘` between `⌷` and `∊` is needed because `∊` is called monadically, so it is *index the enlisted*. And we change `f⍨⍳` into `⍳ f ⍳` to avoid calling f (`*∘⍳¨`) monadically (whenever `⍨` and `¨` are adjacent, they may swap position).

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
:t!^RXzG)
```

Indexing is 1-based. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36pEMS4oospd8/9/Q1MA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmfEOH136pEMS4oospL879LyH9DLiMuYy5TLkMDLkMjLkNTAA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `5` as an example.

```
:     % Implcit input n. Push range [1 2 ... n]
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5]
t!^   % Matrix of all pair-wise powers
      % STACK: [1    2    3    4    5;
                1    4    9   16   25;
                1    8   27   64  125;
                1   16   81  256  625;
                1   32  243 1024 3125]
R     % Upper triangular matrix
      % STACK: [1    2    3    4    5;
                0    4    9   16   25;
                0    0   27   64  125;
                0    0    0  256  625;
                0    0    0    0 3125]
Xz    % Nonzeros. Reads values in column-major order
      % STACK: [1; 2; 4; 3; 9; ...; 625; 3125]
G)    % Get n-th entry (1-based). Implcit display
      % STACK: 9
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
@s^RSdSh
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40s%5ERSdSh&input=14&debug=0)

-1 thanks to [Steven H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55696/steven-h).

0-indexed.

Comment: `@s^RSdSh` to golf a byte off.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ƒNDLm`}I@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2CQ/F5/chFpPh///TQE)

**Explanation**

1-indexed.

```
ƒ           # for N in range [0 ... input]
 N          # push N
  DL        # push range [1 ... N]
    m       # raise N to the power of each in [1 ... N]
     `      # flatten to stack
      }     # end loop
       I@   # get the element at index (input)
```

**Alternative solution over a list instead of a loop**

```
ÝεDLm}˜sè
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to  Nahuel Fouilleul*

```javascript
f=(x,n=1)=>x>n?f(x-n,n+1):n**x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ62ymgdBXoJ1FzEUhW2TEbr/eu8pXRn3O@w0sezOjBOo5RUxZM28EGtjzFHFl59Sq8JDe5i4HEMQF0X4)

Comment: -1 byte inverting the test `f=(x,n=1)=>x>n?f(x-n,n+1):n**x`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 29 bytes

```perl6
{({|($++X**1..$++)}...*)[$_]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TU7LCoJAFN3fr7iE5YzW2JgJIUXb9i2CigidQDAbmikK88va9WPmqESrczive6W4ZmF1UwLvIYsjOD9xEF8SgfOqIMWLWK67cRzOWE1oyRhz6NY67MuqDi61UBrnmKW5UIR@3kzJLNXE2ykX7dHCxpp4Rl/lOgJzZF03IpDZMUe3qUdwuly7pdECiZXm8qaHaImHFLEWCcUCEFOF5qvOpn/@EHutyE5nTez@RNnULP0CPSirMRqJA2/QB7/BAIIGZzBr9WkInLcMeGDIhPvTLw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  (  # generate the sequence

    {  # code block used to generate each value in the sequence

      |(         # slip the values into the outer sequence

        $++      # post-incremented anonymous state value
        X**      # cross using &infix:«**»
        1 .. $++ # from 1 to post-incremented anonymous state value

      )
    }

    ...          # keep generating values until

    *            # never stop

  )[ $_ ]        # index into the sequence (0-based)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
->n{w=0;n-=w+=1until n<0;w**=w-~n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vutzWwDpP17Zc29awNK8kM0chz8bAulxLy7Zcty6v9n9BaUmxgoaBnp6RgaZebmJBdU1RTVp0UWytlor@fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda N:[n**-~e for n in range(N+2)for e in range(n)][N]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUcHPKjpPS0u3LlUhLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDT9tIEySUihDK04yN9ov9X1CUmVeikJtYoJGmA5UxNDDQ1PwPAA) (0-indexed.)

*0-indexed alternative [74 bytes long version](https://tio.run/##HYwxCoAwEAS/cuVdJGoCgii@RCwEE7XIKUcsbPx6NFYLO7N73nE72Ka0OA8embow7BwRsVVcGFKqbLShylIvLl7C8FPWD/@sKJsvMSj9hErbXKdTPgfG/Ab@EMgbkJlXh6auaUov)*.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

[<sub><s>Probably</s> not optimal.</sub>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148577/53748)

-3 thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)'s golfing.

```
=RṁR€T€µT*FḢ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9826OHOxqBHTWtCgPjQ1hAtt4c7Fv3//9/QCAA)**

Comment: Wow, you must be really tired today.

Comment: I'm actually really ill!

Comment: Sorry! Hope you get better soon!

Comment: Also, [here is some 3 bytes off](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9826OHOxqBHTWtCgPjQ1hAtt4c7Fv3//9/QFAA) I managed to pluck out of this trivially.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 23 bytes

```
(∊n↑¨⊂[2]n∘.*n←⍳n)[n←⎕]
```

Explanation:

```
[n←⎕] prompts for screen input and selects the nth element of the concatenated vector
see below

n←⍳n creates a vector of 1 to n

∘.* outer product with exponentiation as the operator

⊂[2] enclose each row of the resulting array as an element of a nested array

∊n↑¨ take 1 to n elements from the 1 to nth row of the matrix and concatenate into a vector
```

Comment: What APL dialect does this work on?

Comment: It is written in APL+WIN. I will make this clear in any future answers

Comment: I took `∊` from your answer to replace my `↑,/`. I didn't know of that function. Thanks

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I think this will work on any modern APL.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 30+1 (-p) bytes

```
$_-=$.++until$.>$_;$_=$.**++$_
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##Dcg7DoAgEAXA/p1jKzYQUfETglehsiAhQBSv7@qU084rOyETrBeKOpBhfkpPmcxB0VP8RylmiiIDLEZMmOGwYMWG/a2tp1pu0S1/)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
{1,[:;[:(^&.><\)1+i.
```

1-indexed

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxgq6dgoGClYPC/2lAn2so62kojTk3PziZG01A7U@@/JpeSnoJ6mq2VuoKOQq2VQloxV2pyRr5CmoKh6f//AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 45 bytes

```
readIO
lblb
a+1
i-a
if i b
i+a
a^i
printInt a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058rJykniStR25ArUzeRKzNNIVMhiStTO5ErMS6Tq6AoM6/EM69EIfH///@GpgA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure 51 bytes

0-indexed, for example input `9` returns `256.0`.

```
#(nth(for[i(range)j(range i)](Math/pow i(inc j)))%)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C <del>76</del>, 62 bytes

```
y;f(n){for(y=0;n>y*++y/2;);return(int)pow(y-1,n+y*(3-y)/2-1);}
```

<del>y;f(n){y=(int)(-.5+sqrt(1+8*~-n)/2)+2;n+=y*(3-y)/2-1;return(int)pow(y-1,n);}</del>

[I based it on this code](https://gist.github.com/PhDP/2358809)

[Try it on ideone](https://ideone.com/M7oIeU)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

1-indexed

```
←000`ŕŕ⁺ĐĐř^Đ04Ș↔+⇹Ł-Đ↔3Ș0>łŕ0↔⇹+⁻⦋↔ŕ
```

Explanation:

Briefly, it calculates each row. If the requested number is in that row, return it; otherwise, go to the next row.